# Get Dropped Image Src

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I know Drag&Drop Questions have been asked a lot , but I searched everywhere and couldn't find  what I want.

I'm trying to make a simple div where you can drop an image from the another website and get its src for later use.

Comment: isnt this the same ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170812/get-src-from-draggable-img

Comment: Nope , I need something that gets the information of images dropped from another websites , if for example I want to drag an image from http://somesite.com/ to my website . the dropped image is not already in my website